# Changing all child elements style using inline CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some html like this:

```
<div>
   <p>Hello</p>
   <h1>Hi</h1>
   <p>What</p>
</div>
```

How can I change the font-family of all html elements inside the div element using inline CSS?

I know I can do that by applying style in each element inside the div, I just want to know is there any way to do that by applying style only in the div element?

Comment: `div p, div h1 {}` or `div * {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
<div style="font-family:'Segoe UI'">
  .....
</div>
```

it takes effect in all children inside the div.